# Postfix body hash did not verify / First Hop of headers contains local address

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, dkim, spamassassin

So far my mailserver works, all checks pass with almost highest scores. But one thing I wonder is why I get a DKIM authenticated problem on mxtoolbox, when sending a mail via smtp.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebmot.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nhAe.png)

When sending via roundcube, I don't usually get this problem, tho roundcube is also configured to send to the same smtp server, not localhost even though it is on the same server.

Also when analyzing the headers of a message sent by my mailserver, I saw that the first Hop contains my local LAN IP address:

```
From: unknown ::ffff: 192
By: mail.example.com (my correct mailserver Domain)
```

Not sure if this is a problem or if this is normal behavior.